# Problem with select2 in angularjs, select2 is displayed but does not work

Tags: angular, jquery-select2

I using adminlte template, it is includes select2.
for using select2 I created a directive to init select2:

`select2.directive.ts`

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[appSelect2]'
})
export class Select2Directive implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(this.el.nativeElement).select2({ width: '100%' });
  }
}
```

I using this directive on a html select tag, select2 style loaded and show it perfect but problem is that on select or deselect the field isn't dirty, no thing change on formControl.

```
<select appSelect2 multiple [formControl]="selected_roles">
    <option *ngFor="let rol of roles" [value]="rol.id">{{ rol.display_name }}</option>
</select>
```

In this example that I wrote, the selected_roles dosn't changed.

I also included select2 js and css on angular.json file.

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css",
  "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/overlayScrollbars/css/OverlayScrollbars.min.css",
  "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css",
  "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/select2/css/select2.css",
  "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/css/adminlte.min.css",
  "src/assets/css/materialdesignicons.min.css",
  "src/assets/css/fa-fonts.css",
  "src/assets/css/custom-mat.scss",
  "src/assets/css/rtl.css",
  "src/styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js",
  "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
  "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/overlayScrollbars/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.min.js",
  "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js",
  "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/select2/js/select2.js",
  "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/select2/js/i18n/fa.js",
  "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js",
  "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"
]
},
```

Am I doing something wrong to using select2?

I using angular 14.0.2

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Use [this library](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap). [Demo](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/advanced/select2)